# Phoenix: default path for no route found

Tags: redirect, elixir, phoenix-framework, router

Let's look at a basic router:

```
...
scope "/", Backend do
  pipe_through [:browser, :with_session]

  get "/", PageController, :index
end
...
```

calling http://localhost:4000/login raise the default "Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError".
What's the best approach to handle this situation?
Leaving the default phoenix error page?
Redirect to index page?
Redirect to a custom page not found?

How to redirect any unknown route to a single path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What's the best approach to handle this situation?

There is no best approach. I personally prefer to show a 404 message on the same URL so that if the user made a typo, they are able to edit and fix the URL instead of having to retype the exact URL again, which they'll have to do if the site redirects invalid URLs to somewhere.

If you still want to redirect, you can create a catch-all route at the end of the scope block and a simple controller:

```
# Controller
defmodule MyApp.FourOhFour do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    redirect(conn, to: "/404")
  end
end

# Route
scope "/", MyApp do
  get "/*path", FourOhFour, :index
end
```

The above will redirect all unknown GET requests to `/404`. Make sure this route comes after all your `get` calls.